# Create Surrogate Keys, from 2 tables

Tags: join, google-bigquery, surrogate-key

I need to create surrogate key and add it as a new column to the tables
My case is :

Table1:

| Product_ID | Product_Unique_ID | NEW COLUMN with surrogate key |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 123-aaa | 123-123-aaaa |
| 123 | 123-bbb | 123-123-bbb |
| 456 | null | 456 |
| 789 | 789-aaa | 789-789-aaaa |

contrain is that in Table2
I have only Product_Id without Product Unique ID so how can i create surrogate key for it? if for case 123 there are 2 unique ids ?

Answer (score 0):

First, for each `Product_ID` one `surrogate key` is to be set. One method is to group table1 by `Product_ID` and use an aggregation for the `surrogate key`. This can be `any_value`, `min`, `max` or even `array_agg`.

```sql
WITH
 tbl AS (
 SELECT
 Product_ID,
 NULLIF(Product_ID,"456") || "-" || TEMP AS Product_Unique_ID 
 FROM
 UNNEST(SPLIT("123,456,789")) AS Product_ID WITH OFFSET,
  UNNEST(SPLIT("aaa,bbb")) AS TEMP
 WHERE OFFSET =0 OR TEMP="aaa" ),
 tbl1 AS (
 SELECT *, Product_ID || IFNULL("-"||Product_Unique_ID,"") AS surrogate_key
 FROM tbl),
 tbl2 AS (SELECT *, rand() as some_value_tbl2 FROM UNNEST(SPLIT("123,456,789")) as Product_ID),
 tbl1_grp AS ( SELECT Product_ID, ANY_VALUE(surrogate_key) as surrogate_key FROM tbl1 GROUP BY 1 )

SELECT
 *
FROM tbl2
LEFT JOIN tbl1_grp
USING(Product_ID)
```